# LARAVEL 5.5 - Saving arrays to database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've got an array which I've passed into my view which consists of the following:

```
array:353 [▼
0 => "Company name"
1 => "Another name"
....
]
```

Suppose a user has selected both options above. Whilst I'm able to successfully save multiple choice options from the form in my database, I need to save the name rather than the number. For example, in phpmyadmin, the target_companies column is saved as ["0", "1"] rather than [Company name", "Another name"].

I'm passing this data into my view with the following:

```
$companies = DB::table('vacancies')->distinct()->select('company')->pluck('company')->toArray();
```

In my view, I've got this:

**VIEW**

```
<div class="form-group">
  {{ Form::label('target_companies', 'Select Company')}}
  {{ Form::select('target_companies[]', $companies, null, ['multiple'=>true, 'class'=>'form-control']) }}
</div>
```

And in my controller, I've got the following:

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
  $this-> validate($request, [
      'target_sector' => 'required|max:255',
      'target_skillsets' => 'required|max:255',
      'target_companies'=> 'required|max:255',
      'target_locations'=> 'required|max:255',

  ]);
  //Create Post
  $id = Auth::user()->id;
  $admin = Admin::find($id);
  $admin->target_companies = $request->input('target_companies');
  $admin->target_sector = $request->input('target_sector');
  $admin->target_skillsets = $request->input('target_skillsets');
  $admin->target_locations = $request->input('target_locations');

  $admin->save();

  return redirect('/admin')->with('success', 'Preferences Updated', 'admin',$admin);
}
```

Finally, the model has this:

```
protected $casts= [
 'target_companies'=> 'array',
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to receive the company names back from your form inside of the array, you can simply adjust your `pluck` method in the controller like so:

```
$companies = DB::table('vacancies')->distinct()->select('company')->pluck('company', 'company')->toArray();
```

The second argument of the `pluck` method will be the keys. If omitted, it will be an indexed array

Now you will be passing an array to your view like this:

```
array:353 [▼
    "Company name" => "Company name"
    "Another name" => "Another name"
    ....
]
```

And your select form's value will be the keys (company name) which will be passed back to the controller for saving data. Is that what you wanted to do?

Comment: Glad I could help!